# Matching dashes and newlines with Lua pattern

Tags: string, lua, split, newline

I am trying to split this file with the delimiter of 2 line breaks, 4 dashes in a row (----) and another 2 line breaks. Basically `\n\n----\n\n`.

The pattern I'm tossing into *gmatch* is `"([^\n\n----\n\n]+)"` but for some reason it's also matching instances of `----` that don't have the line breaks around it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape `-` with `%-`.